# how to build trading platform using highchart realtime chart?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, trading, highcharts-ng

I want to build a platform for trading like expertoption.com and iqoption.com so can you please tell me how to build this system using the highchart real-time chart.

```
            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function () {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.random();
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}....
```

Comment: Hi @avinash puri, What exactly do you want to achieve? Highcharts is a JS library that presents data on a chart. The data is independent of Highcharts and you must provide it by yourself.

Comment: I want to build a trading system which includes a real-time data chart of stock.

Comment: avinash puri - Can you specify your question? What exactly is your problem? Please check the docs about working with data: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro